# How to receive all contacts according to filter set in People Hub?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, contacts

I have 4 accounts set in my People Hub (**Windows Live Id, LinkedIn, Twitter** and **Facebook**). I have unchecked in "*People Hub\filter my contact list*" **twitter** and **facebook** accounts so now I don't see them in my address book - good. But when I am trying to obtain them in code by:

```
var contacts = new Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts();
contacts.SearchCompleted += (s, e) => ...
contacts.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
```

I receive all of the my accounts including **Twitter** and **Facebook** ones - How can I prevent it? I have found property `contacts.Accounts` but it returns {Windows Live Id, Facebook}

Answer (score 2):

Each of the Contacts that are returned also have an Accounts property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contact.accounts(v=vs.92).aspx

You could filter your result using

```
contacts.SearchCompleted += (s,e) => e.Results.Where(c=>MyFilter(c.Accounts))
```

Remember that some contacts might be merges of info from multiple accounts.

```
var allAccounts = Contacts.Accounts;
var interestingAccounts = allAccounts.Where(x=>x.Name!="Twitter") // or x.Kind
bool Myfilter(IEnumerable<Account> accounts)
{
  return accounts.Intersect(interestingAccounts).Any();
}
```

EDIT:

```
bool Myfilter(IEnumerable<Account> accounts)
{
  return accounts.Intersect(Contacts.Accounts).Any();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but contacts.Accounts returns me "Windows Live Id" and "Facebook", but in the People Hub's filter the "Windows Live Id" and "Linked In" is checked... (as I wrote in the question)

Comment: you can still filter the individual contacts

Comment: Sorry but still I don't understand how to receive checked accounts in People Hub's filter when Contacts.Account returns me wrong info (Hard-coding is not a solution)

Comment: Sorry. Is misread the contents of your Contacts.Accounts property